# The bgcolor changes to "yellow" after using onclick. The changed color should be on the clicked box even after a page reload..How can I acheive it..?

Tags: html

```
function getid(obj){obj.style.backgroundColor="yellow";var finaltime=time;document.getElementById("txt2").value=finaltime;}
<table><br>
td bgcolor="green" onclick="getid(this)"  8-9 <br>
td bgcolor="green" onclick="getid(this)" 9-10 <br>
td bgcolor="green" onclick="getid(this)" 10-11 <br>
</table >
```

form action="member.php" method="post"
//I want to post the seleted 'td' value to the database and keep the selected td's bgcolor to yellow"
input type="submit" name="submit" value="confirm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web is stateless, which means that when a new page loads, anything that happened before is not preserved.  You would have to store the id of the td as well as the color it should be somewhere, e.g. in your db, in the url for the next page, in a cookie, in a session variable, etc.  Then the next page would have to read in the information and set the style again.